# How to fix Node call function multiple times?

Tags: node.js

I am creating cron in node, but when I hit my server.js file function hit multiple times and send multiple mails.

Actually I hit function directly on server run. Please guide me what is the correct way to call a function in node.

**Code**

```
var app = express();

app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

// cron.schedule("0 0 * * 0", () => {
//   runStaffCron();
// });

runStaffCron();
```

**Function**

```
const runCron = () => {
  
  var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
    var chunks = [];

    res.on("data", function (chunk) {
      chunks.push(chunk);
    });

    res.on("end", function () {
      var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
      const data = JSON.parse(body.toString("utf-8"));
      const emails = [];
      data.contact_sample.forEach((subscriber) => {
        emails.push(subscriber.email);
      });
      getStaffJobs().then((jobs) => {
        var mailPayload = {
          to: emails,
          from: "test@gmail.com",
          templateId: "my-template-id",
          dynamicTemplateData: {
            subject: "Testing Templates",
            name: "Some One",
            city: "Denver",
            week: "August 24 2020",
          },
        };
        for (let i = 0; i < jobs.length; i++) {
          const desc = cheerio.load(jobs[i].job_description.substring(0, 250), {
            xmlMode: true,
          });

          const key = i + 1;
          mailPayload.dynamicTemplateData["job" + key] = {
            header: jobs[i].job_title,
            body: desc.html() + " ...",
            cta: "Apply now",
            url: `http://www.thestaffingconnection.ca/job/${jobs[i].job_slug}`,
          };
        }
        // console.log(mailPayload);
        mail(mailPayload);
        return;
      });
    });
  });
  req.write("{}");
  req.end();
};

module.exports = runCron;
```

Any solution appreciated!

Comment: Are you meaning to tell that you want to run a cron job but unable to?

Comment: Actually function hit multiple times

Comment: Actually function hit multiple times

Comment: // cron.schedule("0 0 * * 0", () => {
//   runStaffCron();
// }); -----> This code hits multiple times when un-commented?

runStaffCron(); -----> I can understand this is hit every time you restart the server

Comment: Yes you r right

Answer (score 0):

The below code worked for me. You can probably use any other npm package similar to node-schedule.

```js
var schedule = require('node-schedule');
schedule.scheduleJob('*/10 * * * *', function () {
    require('dns').resolve('www.google.com', function (err) {
      if (err) {

      } else {
        
      }
    });
  });
```